# How to add a 3rd Option

Tags: php, operators

I have this code snippet

```
if (!empty($_POST['dropdownOption'])) {     $orderBy = ($_POST['orderValue'] == "date") ? "date" : "price";     $orderType = (!empty($_POST['orderType'])) ? "DESC" : "ASC";     $quer = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE case= 'apartment' ANDfield= 'sell' ORDER BY ".$orderBy." ".$orderType."";     $query = mysqli_query($connect, $quer) or die(mysqli_error()); }
```

User select from a form

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="orderValue">
    <option value="date">order by date</option>
    <option value="price">order by price</option>
</select><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="orderType" value="1">In descending order?</input><br>
<input type="submit" name="dropdownOption" value="Apply">
```

I'm not familiar with the ?: operator temary so I'm not following how this outputs the selected value. I want to add a 3rd value but I don't understand how this works so I'm lost. Maybe I have to re-write the $orderBy = ($_POST['orderValue'] == "date") ? "date" : "price";

Any help?

Comment: The conditional operator is used to pick one of two values depending on a condition. Since you no longer have two values to pick from, it isn't a good choice here. You therefore don't need to be familiar with it. Scrap it and rewrite the logic from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did it like this:

$orderBy = $_POST['orderValue'] ;

I set a default value if I want

Not quite sure why the code snippet I picked up was written the way it was - still don't understand the

```
$orderBy = ($_POST['orderValue'] == "date") ? "date" : "price";
```

The above seems much simpler but if anyone can explain it may be useful.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.